# PyPDF2 complete clone of file

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to copy a PDF in its entirety using PyPDF2, the following code copies the content but not the outline of the pdf.

[here is a sample pdf](http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf) and use the code as follows `python test.py <input pdf> <output dest>`

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import sys
import os.path

def main(argv):
    if not os.path.isfile(argv[0]) and \
    not os.path.isfile(argv[1]):
        print("Invalid path")
        sys.exit()
    input_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(argv[0], "rb"))
    output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
    input_pdf_pages = input_pdf.getNumPages()
    for i in range(0, input_pdf_pages):
        output_pdf.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(i))
    output_pdf.write(open(argv[1], "wb"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: If you want to end up with a perfect copy, why not copy the entire file instead?

Comment: I am trying to modify contents of the pdf, but the first step is to make a proper copy of the pdf.

Answer (score -1):

`PdfFileWriter` does have a number of methods for copying an entire file: `appendPagesFromReader`, `cloneReaderDocumentRoot`, and `cloneDocumentFromReader`.

However, I can't get them to work properly either. ;-) You might have better luck.

Answer (score -1):

probably not a 100% exact replica, but...

```
for i in range(input_pdf.getNumPages()): output_pdf.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(i))
```

Comment: This is already mentioned in the question: `for i in range(0, input_pdf_pages):
        output_pdf.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(i))`. Make sure you read the question thoroughly before answering.